# Cursor position is at end in Firefox using div contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, safari

I am forced to use `<div contenteditable="true" class="div-contenteditable"></div>`, which is making the cursor position at the end in Firefox when it is empty and the issue happens only on first click, on second click to the same div the cursor sets back to starting position.[image]

When I write something inside it and the delete the complete text , click outside that div and click it back again, I face that issue again.
On typing, the cursor automatically fixes its position and sets to the right place. Css which I have written is

```
.div-contenteditable {
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border: unset;
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: relative;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-height: 41px;
}

.div-contenteditable:before {
    content: "\feff";
}
```

I am using display: block; becuase in Safari using inline-block makes the cursor size bigger than div.

I tried adding `&zwnj;`
before div element starts and end, then the div shifts little down and then I don't get the cursor issue in FF.
I tried adding `<br />` inside div but it didn't fix the FF issue. Please help me out as I am new to HTML ans CSS

```css
.div-contenteditable {
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border: unset;
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: relative;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-height: 41px;
}

.div-contenteditable:before {
    content: "\feff";
}
```

```html
<table> <thead> <tr> <th>English</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr><td><div contenteditable="true" class="div-contenteditable"></div></td></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: please add html code also

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. https://jsfiddle.net/etrzukmp/ And, off topic, but what's with the BOM?

Comment: @XenioGracias:
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>English</th> </tr> </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr><td><div contenteditable="true" class="div-contenteditable"></div></td></tbody>
</table>

I guess this can help you out

Comment: Don't add code in the comment add it in a question description

Comment: I have created a code snippet based on the code that you have provided.. I cannot see any textbox in the code. @Shailesh Prajapati

Comment: Run the code snippet and click on the top left corner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work using display: block,
I faced few issues in margin to did set margin also, it worked for me in all browsers